# Try Joomla, Drupal and other PHP CMS package online?

Tags: drupal, joomla

Is there any website that allows me to try joomla, or drupal online?

Basically I want to learn Joomla and Drupal, but don't feel like download the whole source and install it on my computer and start configuring it. I would prefer an online service ( preferably free!) that allows me to do just that.

Is there any such websites available?

Answer (score 1):

The individual websites for each usually have a demo!

Joomla: http://demo.joomla.org/
Drupal: http://php.opensourcecms.com/scripts/details.php?scriptid=191

Opensourcecms.com has many CMS's on it also, and most have links to their demos.

Answer (score 1):

One handy way to quickly try various web apps is to use a pre-built virtual machine. Here's one place to get them:

http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/cat/502

Simply download the VM and start it up. Each one is a fully configured system with the application already installed. You can work with Drupal, Joomla, WordPress, and many more. When you're done trying it out or if you want to start fresh, just throw it a way and grab a new one.

Once you get a hang for something through the VM, though, it's definitely worth taking the time to practice installing and configuring it.

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal Use : Use http://simplytest.me/

It allows you to install and evaluate any Contributed Module, Theme, Distributions.

Answer (score 0):

I've created an app where you can try out different CMS / webshops: http://opstack.info:3000  - it doesn't even require you to register, only if you want to keep it alive longer. Currently Joomla, Drupal, Wordpress, Magento, Opencart, Typo3 is available, but as it's easy to extend, the list will grow.